# Gulp no longer working after upgrading to node.js 4.1

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I just upgraded from node 0.12.x to 4.1.0. After doing so `gulp` no longer works. Here is what I'm seeing in the console after I try to run `gulp`

```
module.js:338
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/cache/4.5.103.35.flags.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:25:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
```

I've tried running `npm install`, and updating to the latest version of `gulp` but that didn't fix the problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you also reinstall global dependencies or just the local ones?

Comment: Had same issue. Fixed by installing nvm and going using an older node (0.12.7)

Comment: I got it working by reverting to an older version of gulp.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix it by deleting the "npm" and "npm-cache" folders in "/usr/local/".

Then do a

```
 "npm install -g npm"
```

Followed by:

```
"npm install -g gulp"
```

Everything should now be updated and ready to rock!

EDIT:
On Windows the folders can be found in "/users/(username)/AppData/Roaming"

Answer (score 5):

Delete the Gulp module in the error, so in your case delete this folder

```
/Users/me/.node/lib/node_modules/gulp
```

Then clean your npm cache:

```
$ npm cache clean
```

And finally install Gulp globally again:

```
$ npm install -g gulp
```

Then you should find it works again - I did!

Comment: This worked for me, I was upgrading to node v4.4.0 LTS from v0.10.35